# Drag and drop items in a GridView

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-gridview

I gridview in my app. I want to rearrange the GridView Items by dragging and dropping them. Suppose 1st item is dragged onto the second item, their positions should be replaced. I tried implementing the way Home Screen of Android does. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout this [library](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/pageddragdropgrid/). It is inspired by Karan_Rana's link.

Edit: The above library has been deprecated. A library that is in active development can be found here: [DynamicGrid](https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid)

Comment: @AmitJayaswal I have edited the post with an updated library.

Answer (score 2):

For drag and drop in Grid view please check the following tutorial:

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/

This could help you